# What does と after volitional form mean?

Tags: syntax

What does と right after 乗り込もう mean in the following sentence?

> 一人で原始林へ**乗り込もうと**は君はなんて勇ましいんだ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theory 1 -** 
大辞林 第三版の解説：

とは（ 連語 ）〔格助詞「と」に係助詞「は」が付いたもの〕
。。。

（３）驚き・怒り・感動などの気持ちを表す。 「まさか優勝する－思わなかった」 。。。

According to the Daijirin dictionary defintion [とは] can be a compound-case-marking-particle used to express surprise, anger, depth of emotion.

**Theory 2 -** 
It could also be viewed as a contraction of

一人で原始林へ乗り込もうと（するの）は君はなんて勇ましいんだ

or

一人で原始林へ乗り込もうと(考えるの）は君はなんて勇ましいんだ

with the part in brackets () omitted.

I am unsure whether these two theories are congruent or incongruent.